# latitude 7390 2-in-1 + dell dock + displayport = no screen wakeup

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, dell, docking, detect

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 7390 2-in-1 with a Dell docking station through usb-C. I have the following devices connected to the docking station:

- keyboard
- mouse
- ethernet cable
- webcam
- monitor through displayport

When I connect the docking station to the laptop, everything is automatically detected with the exception of the monitor.

I can get the monitor to be automatically detected only if I disconnect the monitor cable from the docking station and then reconnect it while the docking station is connected to the laptop.

I have also tried to unplug the power supply to the docking station and re-plug it while everything was connected. In this case the monitor wakes up, but only to show that there is no signal to the displayport input. The laptop does not show any sign of detecting the monitor in this case.

This setup was working fine before, so it must be related to some kernel update. Details below:

- Ubuntu version 22.04.3
- Gnome version 42.9
- Graphics (on laptop) Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
- kernel version: 5.15.0-82-generic
- BIOS version (laptop): latest while writing (1.31.0)
- BIOS/firmware version (docking station): I don't know how to check that